# Trying to solve Top K Frequent Elements using a LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm trying to solve [LeetCode #347. Top K Frequent Elements](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/description/). I know of a few approaches to this problem, but I'm trying to do it the following way.

1) Take the input array, for example: [1,1,1,2,2,3]

2) Create a map of the integer->frequency of its appearance, ie. {[1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1]}

3) Create a LinkedList with Nodes that contain the integer->frequency pairs and insert elements into this LinkedList in ascending orders of frequency, ie. head->[1,3]->[2,2]->[3,1]->null

4) Print the first k value elements of this LinkedList, ie. [1, 2]

Which should theoretically give me the correct answer.

I'm using the following implementation:

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
        /*  input: [1,1,1,2,2,3], 2
            result: [1,3]
            expected: [1,2]
        */

        //stores integer->frequency pairs
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        Node sortedList = null; //head node of list

        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //result array

        //populate map with integer->frequency pairs
        for(int i : nums) {
            if(map.containsKey(i)) {
                map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
            } else {
                map.put(i, 1);
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(map);

        //go through map
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            Integer value = entry.getValue();

            List<Integer> pair = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //make a pair
            pair.add(key);
            pair.add(value);

            //System.out.println(pair);

            Node newNode = new Node(pair);

            System.out.println(newNode.data);

            if(sortedList == null) {
                //System.out.println(newNode.data);
                newNode.next = sortedList;
                sortedList = newNode; //insert at head if linked list is empty
            } else {
                Node current = sortedList; //point current to head
                //move current pointer until we find a spot where current's frequency is less than newNode's frequency
                while(current.next != null && current.next.data.get(1) < newNode.data.get(1)) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                    newNode.next = current.next;
                    current.next = newNode;
            }

        }

        int count = 0;

        //loop until k and return first k keys
        while(sortedList != null && count < k) {
            //System.out.println("key:"+sortedList.data.get(0) + " value:"+ sortedList.data.get(1));
            res.add(sortedList.data.get(0));
            sortedList = sortedList.next;
            count++;
        }


        return res;
    }

    class Node {     
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Node next;

        Node(List<Integer> pair) {
            data = pair;
        }
    }
}
```

However, for some reason my LinkedList is populating as head->[1,3]->[3,1]->[2,2]->null instead of the proper sorted manner. I've tried debugging it but have not been able to figure out which part I'm messing up. I've also written it out on paper and it seems to work so I'm sure I'm messing something up in my code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use a max heap instead of a linked list, better performance

Comment: Your sort algorithm is flawed.  Say you insert an item with frequency 2, and then an item with frequency 3.  The frequency 3 item should now be at the head of the list (i.e., `sortedList` should now point at the freq. 3 item).  But, once the first-ever item has been entered into the list, nothing ever again changes `sortedList`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson my while loop would propagate that item with frequency 3 to the head.

Comment: @FlameDra There are only two options: 1) `sortedList = newNode` when `sortedList` is null, or 2) `current.next = newNode` when `sortedList` is not null. Nothing in your code will set `sortedList = newNode` when `sortedList` is not null. In other words, Kevin is right.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in piece of code where you are trying to insert into linked list into sorted order. First thing is that you start comparing from `current.next.data` you should start comparison from very first node. Second you were not handling case  when element has to be inserted at last node and also at very first node. and you have condition `<` which means it will inserted In decreasing order.

Inside the map iteration code **replace** `if else` condition with below code.It works fine

```
 if(sortedList == null) {
                    //System.out.println(newNode.data);
                    newNode.next = sortedList;
                    sortedList = newNode; //insert at head if linked list is empty
                } else {
                    Node current = sortedList; //point current to head
                    Node prev=null;
                    //move current pointer until we find a spot where current's frequency is less than newNode's frequency
                    while(current != null && current.data.get(1) > newNode.data.get(1)) {
                        prev=current;
                        current = current.next;
                    }
                    if(current==null) {
                        prev.next=newNode;
                    }else if(current==sortedList) {
                        newNode.next=current;
                        sortedList=newNode;
                    }
                    else {
                        newNode.next = current.next;
                        current.next = newNode;
                    }


                }
```

Here if `current==null` means data has to be inserted at last and last node and at that time **last node** will be referenced by **prev** so `prev.next=newNode;`will assign newNode to last.
if `current==sortedList` means data has to be inserted at first node. otherwise data needs to be inserted in middle.